# Pregex Matching Issues

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am trying to use preg_replace on a string to get rid of empty attributes however the entire string is being wiped out.

The string I am doing replacement on looks like this:

```
 <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="required" size="20" maxlength="40" value="" />
```

Here is the code I am trying to use:

```
    $defaults = array(
        'cols' => '60',
        'class' => '',
        'currentValue' => '',
        'default' => '',
        'group' => '',
        'id' => '',
        'maxlength' => '',
        'name' => '',
        'options' => array(),
        'rows' => '00',
        'size' => '60',
        'text' => '',
        'type' => 'text',
        'value' => ''
    );
    $inputHTML = '<input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="required" size="20" maxlength="40" value="" />';
    $inputHTML = preg_replace( '/(' . implode( '|', array_keys( $defaults ) ) , ')=""/g', '', $inputHTML );
```

The array is being used since I need for other portions of the code.

Any ideas why the string comes back blank?

Comment: If you have enabled error reporting, you would have noticed an error. Hint: There is no "g" modifier in php.

Comment: Also, the comma after the implode call should be a period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `,` instead of a `.` in your `preg_replace` call. <s>Also, you have a `""` in your regex, so it will only catch empty attributes</s> (oh, that was exactly what you wanted to do).

Corrected line:

```
$inputHTML = preg_replace( '/(' . implode( '|', array_keys( $defaults ) ) . ')=""/', '', $inputHTML );
```

Working example: http://ideone.com/sO9K9S

Comment: Thanks, I've been staring at code too much for the last week.